# Ansible - add list of IPs to the Windows firewall allow list

Tags: loops, ansible

I want to restrict port 443 on the Windows Server. I have the following task at the moment which works.

```yaml
- name: Firewall rule to allow HTTPs
  win_firewall_rule:
    name: Apache Webserver
    localport: 443
    action: allow
    direction: in
    protocol: tcp
    state: present
    enabled: yes
    remoteip: 192.168.61.61
```

What is the correct way to add multiple ip addresses for remoteip from item list? with example the following list:

```yaml
ip_addresses:
  - name: Apache Webserver Rule 1 
    ip: 127.0.0.1
  - name: Apache Webserver Rule 2 
    ip: 192.168.61.61
  - name: Apache Webserver Rule 3 
    ip: 1.1.1.1
  - Name: Apache Webserver Rule ..
    ip: 1.0.0.1
```

When I do this it does not work:

```
    remoteip: "{{ item.ip | default('any') }}"
    state: present
    force: yes
  loop:
    - "{{ ip_addresses }}"
```

This method only adds the last item in the list. When I run this the scope is not added with IP:

Output

```
ok: [s1.example.com] => (item=[{'name': 'Apache Webserver Rule 1', 'ip': '127.0.0.1'}, {'name': 'Apache Webserver Rule 2', 'ip': '192.168.61.61'}])
```

Answer (score 3):

You're creating the same rule with a new IP address over and over again.
To create rules like this, you need to iterate over a list of hashes to create three unique rules (also, `with_items` is deprecated:

```yaml
ip_addresses:
  - name: Apache Webserver Rule 1
    ip: 127.0.0.1
  - name: Apache Webserver Rule 2
    ip: 192.168.61.61
  - name: Apache Webserver Rule 3
    ip: 1.1.1.1
```

```yaml
- name: Firewall rule to allow HTTPs
  win_firewall_rule:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    localport: 443
    action: allow
    direction: in
    protocol: tcp
    state: present
    enabled: yes
    remoteip: "{{ item.ip }}"
  loop: "{{ ip_addresses }}"
```

The difference between `loop` and `with_*` is described in [this](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#comparing-loop-and-with) Ansible guide.

**EDIT: add several IPs to the same rule**

The `win_firewall_rule`  module documentation says that [`remoteip`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/windows/win_firewall_rule_module.html#parameter-remoteip) parameter also can be a range of IPs. It does not offer an example but [@Noob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6569245/noob) figured out that comma-separation and CIDR notation like `192.168.61.61/24,127.0.0.1` work. So the following task would address the ask to add 4 IP addresses:

```yaml
- name: Firewall rule to allow HTTPs
  win_firewall_rule:
    name: Apache Webserver
    localport: 443
    action: allow
    direction: in
    protocol: tcp
    state: present
    enabled: yes
    remoteip: "127.0.0.1,192.168.61.61,1.1.1.1,1.0.0.1"
```

Comment: What should be the remoteip to apply all the three unique rules since its now a static value? The IP address are added in /etc/ansible/host_var/s1.example.com.

Comment: Oops. I forgot to replace it with the variable, thanks for noticing. I updated the answer, now it's correct.

Comment: You need to remove ":" in the name. I ran it but it didn't add the ips in the scope.

Comment: Thanks again and sorry for the typo. :)

Comment: No problem, the only problem which I have is it's not adding the ips in the scope. the question is updated.

Comment: I don't see the update yet, let's wait for the moderators to review the edits.

Comment: @Noob please run it exactly as in my answer. Currently you're putting a list into another list.

Comment: Changed it as requested, but get this:
>list object' has no attribute 'name'\n\n

Comment: Okay it worked now but the issue is that it created a seperate rule per ip which is not ideal.

Comment: Yeah but that's the idea if a module is running in a loop. The documentation says that [`remoteip`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/windows/win_firewall_rule_module.html#parameter-remoteip) parameter also can be a range of IPs. I'm not sure about the exact syntax though. The documentation does not offer an example and there's [an issue regarding this](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.windows/issues/465) on GitHub since Nov 2022. You can try  to set `remoteip: "127.0.0.1,192.168.61.61,1.1.1.1"` and see if it works.

Comment: This is the syntax:
>remoteip: "192.168.61.61/24,127.0.0.1"

Comment: Ok I'll edit my answer based on what we've figured out.